# Determine whether the center of a $C^*$-algebra is 0

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $A$ be a non-unital $C^*$-algebra. )$(A,G,\alpha)$ is a $C^*$-dynamical sysytem. The space of all continous functions from $G$ to $A$ with compact support is denoted by $C_c(G, A)$. Suppose $f,g\in C_c(G,A)$. The product of $f$ and $g$ is defined as following:

$fg(t)=\int f(r)\alpha_r(g(r^{-1}t))dr, \forall t\in G$.

I wonder whether there exist some propositions to determine when the center of $C_c(G,A)$ is 0?

Comment: Functions of the form $t\to f(t)x$ where $x\in A$ and $f\in C_c(G)$ suggest that $Z(C_c(G,A) = \{0\}$ iff $Z(A)=\{0\}$.

Comment: But not every $f\in C_c(G,A)$ has the form $t\mapsto f(t)x$.

Comment: Could you clarify what algebra product is placed on $C_c(G,A)$. The pointwise product would not seem to use the structure that $G$ is a _group_ in any way...

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the counting measure, since $C_c(\mathbb{Z},A)$ is spanned by maps with singleton support, you can check that $f \in C_c(\mathbb{Z},A)$ is central with respect to convolution iff $f(n) \cdot \alpha_n(a) = a \cdot \alpha_n(f(n))$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and every $a \in A$. I don’t know how much more you can extract without additional information…

Comment: I think in its current form the question is far too broad and almost asking for people to provide both the hypotheses of a theorem as well as its proof. Consider $G$ discrete ICC and $A$ to be abelian and non-unital, for instance

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić,does there exist a concrete example such that the center of $C_c(G,A)$ is 0?

Comment: Yes, by the above observation, take $A = K(H)$ the $C^\ast$-algebra of compact operators on a separable infinite Hilbert space $H$ together with the trivial action of $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Which is $0$ in $K(H) \rtimes_r \mathbb{Z} = K(H) \otimes \mathrm{C}^\ast_r(\mathbb{Z})$. Note that $K(H)$ is non-unital.

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić, excuse me, I have another question. In the example you constructed, $A$ has no tracial states.  If $A$ is aasumed to have a tracial state, does there exist other exmples?

Answer (score 0):

First, $Z(C_c(G,A)) = C_c(G,Z(A))$. Indeed, if there exists an $f\in C_c(G,A)$ and $t\in G$ such that $f(t)\notin Z(A)$, then $f\notin Z(C_c(G,A))$. Thus, $Z(C_c(G,A))\subseteq C_c(G,Z(A))$. $(\supseteq)$ is relatively easier to show.

Second, one can use the functions of the form $t\to \phi(t)x$, where $\phi\in C_c(G)$ and $x\in A$, to show $C_c(G,Z(A)) = \{0\}$ iff $Z(A)=\{0\}$.

Comment: But if $(A,G,\alpha)$ is a $C^*$-dynamical system, the multiplication of $f,g\in C_c(G,A)$ in terms of the integral.

Comment: @math112358 Please edit the question and write down explicitly which product you consider on $C_c(G,A)$ to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I have edited the question.